# regex and file names changes by removing dots except last match AND ignoring first character

Tags: regex

I am using python3 and I am trying to get a file renamer right.
I am using a regular expression with lookahead to match the dots except the last one:

```
\.(?=.*\.)
```

This seemed to work fine, I am replacing the dots with dashes. So:

```
some.other.file.is.here.txt ##=> some-other-file-is-here.txt
```

But I forgot the hidden files! something like

```
.passwords
```

becomes

```
-passwords
```

And I have been trying to make the regex ignore any first character, but I do not get it.

Please help.

Comment: `\.(?=.*\.)` will not replace `.` in `.passwords`

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I should have chosen the example .passwords.txt , then it would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=\w)\.(?!\w+$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CRp3b0/4

`(?<=\w)` - Positive look behind that `.` is followed by word character.

`(?!\w+$)` - Negative look ahead that `.` is not followed by last word.

Comment: I have also found a regex that in addition will also find dots in sequence: (?!^.)\.(?=.*\.)